# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, tensorboard

I was training the model and saved it, now I am trying to load but unable to do. I have seen in previous post as well, but some reference links are not working or some things I tried, still not able to solve the problem.

**Code snippet:**

```
#load model

with tf.io.gfile.GFile(args.model, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
generated_image_1, generated_image_2, generated_image_3, = tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(
        graph_def, 
        input_map={'input_image' : input_tensor, 'short_edge_1' : short_edge_1, 'short_edge_2' : short_edge_2, 'short_edge_3' : short_edge_3}, 
        return_elements=['style_subnet/conv-block/resize_conv_1/output:0', 'enhance_subnet/resize_conv_1/output:0', 'refine_subnet/resize_conv_1/output:0'],  
        producer_op_list=None
    )
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "stylize.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "stylize.py", line 57, in main
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'
```

Note: If need more information about this, will sure post add it here. Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BG: I was getting errors while testing the code.
In my case, it was solved with the help of freeze.py and a few modifications in the training file.
And I found some other useful links while searching query.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142116/using-tensorflow-google-protobuf-message-decodeerror-wrong-wire-type-in-tag)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117938/unable-to-use-trained-tensorflow-model)

Comment: I have error here: ```---> 34     od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph) DecodeError: Error parsing message``` I cannot find a solution in the above 2 links...Can someone help?

Comment: I run the same code both on google colab and ubuntu (locally), the same error...