# Loading and testing a Tensorflow 2 trained model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

i already was able to train a custom TF2 model using this tutorial:
https://neptune.ai/blog/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api

Now im getting stuck with testing this model. The script i use for this is also from a turoial and i changed the paths etc but it still doesnt work... I tried and tried and tried for many hours now but at the time i just got demotivated...

I can resolve many errors but the current one not, maybe anyone can help me. Im quite new to object detection..

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six as urllib    # import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[3]:

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util         # from utils import label_map_util

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util      # from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# In[4]:

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'D:/VSCode/Machine_Learning_Tests/Tensorflow/workspace/exported_models/first_model/saved_model'      # MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/saved_model.pb'                                                                     # PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'D:/VSCode/Machine_Learning_Tests/Tensorflow/workspace/data/label_map.pbtxt'                     # PATH_TO_LABELS = 'training/labelmap.pbtxt'

NUM_CLASSES = 1





# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[6]:

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()                            #   od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.compat.v2.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:      #   with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[7]:

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code

# In[8]:

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# In[9]:

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'images/test/'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(3, 8) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12,8)


# In[10]:

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      image_np = np.array(cv2.imread('Test.jpg'))
      cv2.imshow('image',image_np)
      cv2.waitKey(1)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Thats the code i use to try testing the model

And this is the current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\VSCode\Machine_Learning_Tests\Tensorflow\test\object_detection_tutorial_wwwPythonProgrammingNet__mitBild.py", line 65, in <module>
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439124/google-protobuf-message-decodeerror-error-parsing-message-with-type-tensorflow

Comment: When i trained my model there was no inference_graph.pb created...
I tried '"text_format.Merge(graph_str, od_graph_def)"' but the first argument seems to be false.
error is: NameError: name 'graph_str' is not defined

I seem to habe the same problem from the links but im still not sure how to solve it.

I guess i "just" need a script prebuilt for testing object detection on an image with a TF2 model saved as saved_model.pb where i can adjust paths etc